# How to determine button clicked on multi-button form submit using Jersey?

Tags: jersey

Is there a way to determine which button was clicked on a multi-button form submit using Jersey? Following is my REST POST method for my form with two buttons...

```
@POST
@Timed
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response create(@FormParam("textareacontent") String textareacontent) {

  logger.info("{}", textareacontent.trim());
  // do stuff...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

jersey is a RESTful web service framework that communicates with client via http, but it knows nothing about the details of the client.

I think a workaround would be:

- add a hidden input field "buttonClicked" in the form along with the textareacontent to specify which button was clicked
- when the button is clicked, set the value of hidden field in javascript and submit the form
- get the value of "buttonClicked" on the server side and apply whatever logic you want

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using Javascript, but your workaround would be pretty straightforward.